# Firebird - Concatenando campos que retornam de um case

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird, concatenação-de-string

```
SELECT DP.DATA AS DATA, S.DESCRICAO, COUNT(P.CODIGO) AS QNTD,
  (CASE
        WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) =  CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
          (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
    ELSE
      CAST(0 AS INTEGER)
  END) AS HORAS,
  (CASE
    WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) = CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     CAST(0 AS INTEGER)
    WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
    ELSE
     (CASE
       WHEN ( (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) >  CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
              AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) ) THEN
       ((CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)+ 60) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
     ELSE
       (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
     END)
  END) AS MINUTOS,

  (CASE
   WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) = CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     CAST(0 AS INTEGER)
   WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
   ELSE
     (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
  END) AS SEGUNDOS
FROM DET_PEDIDO DP
INNER JOIN PEDIDO P ON P.PEDIDO = DP.PEDIDO AND P.DATAINI = DP.DATA
INNER JOIN SERVICOS S ON S.CODSERV = DP.CODSERV
WHERE P.DATAINI between '02.01.2020' and '02.01.2020'
```

Eu tenho essa consulta em SQL e preciso concatenar o campo horas, minutos e segundos. Como faço isso no firebird sem usar procedure? Além disso, eu não consegui agrupar as informações iguais. Tipo Firma com valor econ.

[image: A imagem é o resultado que estou obtendo]

O que eu preciso é q fique dessa forma: 00:07:48.

Comment: Me parece que você quer calcular a diferença entre `HORAFIM` e `HORAINICIO`. Neste caso, supondo que seus campos sejam strings, não basta fazer: CAST(HORAFIM AS time) - CAST(horainicio AS time) para obter o intervalo em segundos e, se for o caso, converter para hora:minuto:segundo? Ou ainda utilizar a função DATEDIFF()?

Comment: Não dava para usar a função DATEDIFF() pq o firebird é 1.5. Os campos não eram string. Eu recolvi passando os campos q eram inteiros para String e depois fiz um Cast com tudo.

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi. Como eram seus campos qual o significado deles? Um inteiro representando o quê? Se não eram strings porque você faz substring?

Comment: Os campos eram do tipo dateTime e precisava calcular o tempo q o cliente demorou para ser atendido. Eu utilizei SUBSTRING para pegar somente a hora. Fiz o mesmo para mm e ss e assim eu subtrai o tempo inicial do tempo final. Depois disso, fiz um cast para retornar os campos concatenados (Ex.: 00:10:09).

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o comando pipe "||" (Sem aspas) para concatenar seus alias do seu CASE do seu SQL

```
 (CASE
        WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) =  CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
          (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
    ELSE
      CAST(0 AS INTEGER)
  END) ||
  (CASE
    WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) = CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     CAST(0 AS INTEGER)
    WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
    ELSE
     (CASE
       WHEN ( (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) >  CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
              AND (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) ) THEN
       ((CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)+ 60) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
     ELSE
       (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 4 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
     END)
  END) ||

  (CASE
   WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) = CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     CAST(0 AS INTEGER)
   WHEN (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) > CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER)) THEN
     (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
   ELSE
     (CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAINI FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) - CAST(SUBSTRING(P.HORAFIM FROM 7 FOR 2) AS INTEGER))
  END) AS HMS
```

Como não tenho as tabelas é bom verificar a sintaxe.